# Ritwijas and Purohitas becoming Kshatriya

Tags: mahabharata, kshatriya, brahmanas, priests

While describing the duties of the Brahmanas, Bhishma [says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a075.htm#fr_232)

> They amongst them that become Ritwikas, Purohitas, counsellors, envoys, and messengers, become, O king, equal to Kshatriyas.

Ganguly's footnote says

> A Ritwij is a priest employed on a special occasion. A Purohita is one who always acts as a priest.

What is the actual meaning here? Most of the learned brahmanas are either Ritwijas or Purohitas today.  Even if I ignore today's world, the  sacrifices in Olden days also need Ritwijas?

Answer (score 3):

Ritwij is defined in Manu 2.143 as follows:

> agnadhyeam paka-yajnan agni-stoma-adikan makhan |
>  yah karoti vrito
> yasya sa tasya ritwig iha uchyate ||
>
> 2.143. He who, being (duly) chosen (for the purpose), performs the Agnyadheya, the Pakayagnas, (and) the (Srauta) sacrifices, such as the
> Agnishtoma (for another man), is called (his) officiating priest.

and Purohit is mentioned alongwith Ritwij in the verse given below:

> 7.78. Let him appoint a domestic priest (purohita) and choose officiating priests (ritvig); they shall perform his domestic rites
> and the (sacrifices) for which three fires are required.

Now, Ritwijs are meant to be respected and thus not degraded. But a Brahmin who officiates for an entire village is considered as degraded.

> 3.119. Let him honour with the honey-mixture a king, an officiating priest, a Snataka, the teacher, a son-in-law, a father-in-law, and a
> maternal uncle, (if they come) again after a full year (has elapsed
> since their last visit).
>
> 3.120. A king and a Srotriya, who come on the performance of a sacrifice, must be honoured with the honeymixture, but not if no
> sacrifice is being performed; that is a settled rule.

> 3.152. Physicians, temple-priests (devala), sellers of meat, and those who subsist by shop-keeping must be avoided at sacrifices offered to the
> gods and to the manes.

Ritwijs who work on behalf of the Sudras are only to be blamed.

> 11.42. Those who, obtaining wealth from Sudras, (and using that) offer an Agnihotra, are priests officiating for Sudras, (and hence) censured
> among those who recite the Veda.

However, according to the the 12th Chapter of Manu Smriti, Purohit, Kshatriyas are all manifestations of the middling stage of Rajas (activity):

> 12.46. Kings and Kshatriyas, the domestic priests of kings, and those who delight in the warfare of disputations (constitute) the middling
> (rank of the) states caused by Activity.

(In 12.46 the word that is translated as priest is Purohit and not Ritwij)

So, there is a fundamental similarity between Purohits and Kshatriyas but I could not prove the same for Kshatriyas and Ritwijs from Manu.